# Flat descent and cohomology of quasicoherent sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Proof of fpqc descent for quasicoherent sheaves (its final part with Amitsur complex) looks really similar to proving that quasicoherent sheaves do not have cohomology on affine varieties. Is the second statement a formal consequence or is there any general theory/procedure which relates these two?